# AngularJs email validation specific to domain

Tags: angularjs, validation, email

I want to check my email validity to accept only my specified domain using angularjs...Please anyone help me with an example as early as possible...
Thanks,
Uma

Answer (score 8):

You can use `ng-pattern` to validate your input.

Example (Only email with address@domain.com will be valid):

```
<input type="email" name="email" ng-model="email" ng-pattern="/^[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@domain.com$/"/>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/aartek/WSRMP/

Comment: Looks better than mine, but you might want to adjust that regex (replace .[A-Za-z]{2,4} with .com)

Comment: thnq so much. It has helped me alot.

Comment: What the changes required to validate for multiple domains?

Comment: @SandeepKokate use regex "or" operator `(option1|option2|option3)`. Regex will look like this: `/^[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@(domain.com|domain2.com|anotherdomain.com)$/`

Comment: escape the dot with \. `/^[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@(domain\.com|domain2\.com|anotherdomain\.com)$/`

Answer (score 0):

You can use a javascript function that tests if a string is a valid mail adress on your domain

(replace mydomain.com)

```
function isValidMail(str) { 
     var mailPattern = /^[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@mydomain.com$/; 
     return mailPattern.test(str) 
}
```